# Initializing a struct with malloc

Tags: c

To create a struct I can do one of the following:

```
// Method 1
Item *item = malloc(sizeof(Item));
Item _item = {.name="job"};
item = &_item;

// Method 2
Item *item = malloc(sizeof(Item));
item->name="job";
```

Is there a simpler method to do this? Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
malloc(sizeof(Item)) & (Item) {.name="job"}
```

Here are the two methods: https://godbolt.org/z/MfYGW3

Comment: Method 1 doesn't compile

Comment: Your method 1 is invalid since you assign a value to a type.

Comment: Method 1 loses the reference to your dynamically allocated memory, leading to a memory leak.

Comment: You can do `*item = (Item){.name="job"};`, after the malloc

Comment: Don't use `_item` or `_Item` identifier, for anything. Especially however not a mixture of both of them, where half of the uses seem typos....

Comment: Method 1 is "Allocate this! Then throw that in the trash and use a pointer to this locally-scoped thing so that it will go out of scope the moment this block exits!" Express train to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @M.M it compiles for me.

Comment: Method 2 is how we've been doing this since the dawn of time. You should just accept that and move on, as there's really no way to make this work better without introducing a whole lot of ceremony that accomplishes nothing.

Comment: There's no way that compiles. I get "error: expected identifier or '('" as expected on the `Item` (type definition) = something. You can't lvalue a type.

Comment: @tadman sorry I had a typo (fixed)

Comment: Now it compiles, but it's 100% undefined behaviour.

Comment: @tadman I see. Want to post an answer showing why that method is wrong then, etc. ?

Comment: My comment explains it. Address of temporary variable. Throwing your allocation in the trash. It's just nonsense code that "compiles" but is 100% bugs. You may not realize it's junk, but that's part of learning C. Some things are not obvious without experience.

Comment: @tadman is that because instead of `item` pointing to the memory location it's now pointing to the local stack when I do the reassignment?

Comment: Precisely. That and you just stomped the previous allocation, so that's lost to the void.

Comment: @tadman where's the undefined behaviour?  It's not UB to leak memory

Comment: @M.M It is to assign a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope. A good compiler should warn about that. The memory leak is not undefined behaviour, but caused by the pointer replacement, which is undefined behaviour. The two issues are intertwined here, the bad pointer assignment causes the leak.

Comment: @tadman It's not UB to assign a pointer to local variable that goes out of scope. It would be UB to use that pointer after the variable has gone out of scope, but that doesn't happen in the code posted

Comment: @M.M This is a return value. Presumably it will be used. Assuming it won't be is really quite a statement. When I say "undefined behaviour" I mean, strictly, "using this function as intended" which inherently includes using that pointer. I mean, sure maybe they compile this code and never run it, in which case who cares! Bugs don't exist unless they're exercised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    const char* name;
} Item;

int main() {
    Item* item = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    *item = (Item){.name = "Hello"};
    // do work    
    free(item);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with GCC 10.2.0 `-Wall -Wextra` with no errors or warnings.

Comment: What's the overhead implications here? Is a temporary `Item` created?

Comment: The Standard says "If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block." But, I assume most compilers can optimize it out on `-O3`.

Comment: I know C++ has ways of dealing with this, but I'm not sure about C, which is why I ask. It'd be interesting to see on the assembly level if that phantom item actually exists.

Comment: I quoted from the C11 standard. It explains how compound literals are lvalues, so I don't see how they aren't stack allocated overhead without compiler optimizations. In this case, however, it's a negligible 8 bytes.

Comment: @import -- why does yours use `sizeof(Item)` but the other answers use `sizeof(*item)` ?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate The standard also says that the language is defined in terms of its output, so any "stack usage" is 100% a quality of implementation issue

Comment: Yeah, I was just interpreting "static duration in enclosing block" as stack usage.

Comment: @M.M ithis code will be optimized out completely. Here is a bit different version of it. The object is not created in this trivial example https://godbolt.org/z/MqEd19

Comment: @0___________ I'm aware, I already tested `gcc -S -O3`.

Comment: @0___________ I have used compilers where it didn't (gcc 4.1 variant, -O2) , this would actually consume stack for the duration of the function in according to the size of the literal.

Comment: @M.M that's a large RIP...hopefully gcc 4.1 figured it out on `-O3`?

Comment: IDK, we didn't use O3 since code size was important and that bloats out the code size for negligible (in our code base) gain.  I doubt this would have been an intentional difference between levels though, it was probably just something overlooked by the optimizer entirely

Comment: @M.M I was using compiler which did not optimize at all in the ancient era. Yuor comment I would tag as `compiler palaeontology`

Comment: Hey, I remember when gcc 2.7.2.1 had to be used to compile the linux kernel since the code was so riddled with bugs that happened to work on that compiler. gcc 2.7.2.1 vs 2.9 was like python2 vs python3

Answer (score 3):

Use a compound literal:

```
Item *item = malloc(sizeof *item);
*item = (Item) {
    .name = "job",
};
```

Your first method is incorrect (even without the typo) as you just discard the just `malloc`ed memory. You wanted to write `Item = _item;`

Comment: Not sure how it is better than member-wise initialization though

Comment: @EugeneSh. It automatically initializes all struct fields not mentioned to zero.

Comment: Umm.. use `calloc` if it is a concern.

Comment: @koder -- is doing `sizeof *item` the same as doing `sizeof Item` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That will not work for reusing already allocated memory or reinitializing staticly allocated memory. Compound literals work no matter how the (valid) pointer was obtained.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `calloc` sets all bits zero , which may differ from initializing a field to a zero value .

Comment: Also it is tidier this way if there are multiple fields, rather than having a whole series of `item->` statements

Comment: @carl.hiass `sizeof Item` is a syntax error as `Item` is a type. It could also be `sizeof(Item)` but using the `sizeof *item` with the variable name prevents you from using the wrong type.

Comment: Yeah, there's no difference between `sizeof(Item)` and `sizeof(*item)` except a single extra character.

Comment: @Import Accelerate  `sizeof(*item)` is lest prone to coding error, easier to review and maintain. `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);` is correct on its face.  `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr_t));` obliges a lookup to check for the correct type.  That definition may be quite far from this line of code.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good way to dynamically allocate a `struct` instance *and* initialize its members in the same statement.  You can write your own function to abstract out that operation:

```
struct Item *newItem( const char *name /*,  any additional arguments */ )
{
  struct Item *item = malloc( sizeof *item );
  if ( item )
  {
    item->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
    if ( item->name )
    {
      strcpy( item->name, name );
    }
  }
  /**
   * allocate/assign any additional members here
   */
  return item;
}

int main( void )
{
  struct Item *myItem = newItem( "job" /*, any additional arguments */ );
  ...
}
```

That's about as good as it gets.

**EDIT**

Or you could assign a compound literal to the allocated instance as the other answers show.  This method has the benefit of being a "deep" copy - any members that are themselves pointers to allocated memory will wind up pointing to new instances, not the same instance as the original.

Comment: In any sufficiently non-trivial C code base, Object-Oriented C always shows up at some point.